# Laravel Error 500 after php artisan view:clear

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-artisan

I have an issue on the application which I am developing. On some pages I get 500 internal server error. Everything works fine until I return a view so I have tried the command `php artisan view:clear` but after that all pages are returning 500 internal server error. The code works on my local server without any problem. Anyone have an idea from where the problem comes form?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the log file? If yes, then share them here.

Comment: No, there aren`t any errors in the error log

Comment: Do you have full 777 write permissions for the *storage* folder?

Comment: Have you used Firebug and look inside the text when you click on the 500 error ? it will give you details.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It was a permission issue when the server administrator gave full permissions for the storage folder the problem was solved